# Why does $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$? ( Considering that they are both surds)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$? ( Considering that they are both surds)

From the definition of a nth root that means "what number multiplied by itself n times will get you back to the original number under the root", only justifies for single nth roots. Eg. square root of $49$ is $7$; because $7$ times $7$ gets you $49$. However, this doesn't explain why you can combine two surds together by just multiplying the numbers beneath the roots. Is there a logical proof of this that can make me understand this better?

Comment: Are you talking about products, i.e. $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$? What happens if you square both sides? And then reverse the process?  You may need to assume $a$ and $b$ are non-negative real numbers

Comment: Yes, exactly what my question is

Comment: Is $\sqrt{ab}$ equal to $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}~$? Let $r = \sqrt{a}, ~s = \sqrt{b} \implies 0 \leq r,s.$  Then the right hand side is given by $(r \times s)$.  The left hand side should be that number, which when squared, equals $(a \times b)$.  Is $(r \times s)$ that number?  $(r \times s)^2 = r^2 \times s^2 = a \times b$.  So, yes, $(r \times s)$ is that number.  Therefore the LHS of the equation does equal the RHS of the equation.

Comment: What is a surd?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the definition of $y = \sqrt x$ is "that number $y$ for which $y^2 = x$", and if you also agree that (positive) square roots are unique (there is only one; any two positive numbers $y_1$, $y_2$ with the property that $y_1^2 = x = y_2^2$ must in fact be the same, $y_1 = y_2$), then it is not hard to prove that $\sqrt a \sqrt b = \sqrt {ab}$.

Here is a proof: if you claim that $y_1 = \sqrt a \sqrt b$ and $y_2 = \sqrt{ab}$ are in fact the same, you can demonstrate it by showing that they satisfy the same property; namely, $y_1^2 = y_2^2 = ab$.

Indeed, $y_1^2 = (\sqrt a \sqrt b)^2 = \sqrt a^2 \sqrt b^2$ (by commutativity of multiplication), and $\sqrt a^2 \sqrt b^2 = ab$ by definition of square root.

Likewise, $y_2^2 = \sqrt{ab}^2 = ab$ by definition of square root.

Hence $y_1^2 = y_2^2$, ie each of $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfy the property of "is a square root of $ab$"; since (positive) square roots are unique, then $y_1 = y_2$.

You can present an even shorter proof once you are savvy with definitions; observe $(\sqrt a \sqrt b)^2 = \sqrt a^2 \sqrt b^2 = ab$, then immediately by definition we have $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a \sqrt b$.

Answer (score 1):

If the square root of x is defined to be the positive version you don't need the plus or minus for the proof.
\begin{align}1.\hspace{2mm} (a)(b)=(ab)\end{align} using the property of surds/roots you just explained("what number multiplied by itself n times will get you back to the original number under the root"):\begin{align}2.\hspace{2mm}  (\pm\sqrt{a})(\pm\sqrt{a})(\pm\sqrt{b})(\pm\sqrt{b})=(ab)\end{align}
Next use the commutative property of multiplication when you multiply an even number of plus or minuses you get plus;\begin{align} 3.\hspace{2mm} ((\pm)^4(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b})=(ab)\end{align}The plus or minuses cancel and there are two values being multiplied making a square. \begin{align}(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b})^2= (ab)\end{align} Then use the square root function on both sides you only put the plus or minus on one side because they would cancel otherwise.\begin{align}5a.\hspace{2mm} \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}= \pm\sqrt{ab}\end{align}  The square root is defined as the positive solution for positive numbers so you get :\begin{align}5b.\hspace{2mm} \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}= \sqrt{ab}\end{align}